# Is there a way to set a *global* key value using `pgfkeys`?

Tags: pgfkeys, grouping

The simple answer to this question appears to be "No"; quoting from the pgf manual:

> The setting of a key is always local to the current TeX group.

However, this is very annoying because it means that you can't do something like:

```
\foreach \mykey/\myvalue in {
  long/list,
  of/keys%
} {
  \pgfkeyssetvalue{\mykey}{\myvalue}
}
```

So my next best shot is:

```
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/applicant/.code 2 args={\expandafter\global\expandafter\def\csname applicant@#1\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{#2}}}
\foreach \mykey/\myvalue in {
  long/list,
  of/keys%
} {
  \pgfkeys{/applicant={\mykey}{\myvalue}}
}
\makeatletter
```

but that's not very transparent since to get at the "value", I have to use the macro `\csname applicant@whatever the key name was\endcsname`.  (Also, I'm not very *au fait* with `pgfkeys`, this being my first foray, so I should probably have used something like `/.expand once` or `/.store in`, but that's by the by.)

Is there a better way to circumvent this restriction?  I'd be happy with a new macro for *defining* the key, so `\pgfglobalkeys` would be okay (though in the spirit of `\pgfkeys` it feels more like it ought to be `\pgfkeys{key name/.global=...}` but let's not quibble), but when *using* the key's value then it ought be be accessible via the traditional means, say `pgfkeysgetvalue`.

Comment: I think that all of the key-value solutions take the view that keys are local objects.

Comment: @Joseph: I know that, but it can be annoying (since, as I said, `\foreach` loops are their own little scope) so I'd like to easily circumvent that!

Comment: I guess my point is that this is a problem with `\foreach`, not with the keys side of things!

Comment: @Joseph: So maybe I should have a `\globalforeach` which saves up the contents of the `\foreach` and then puts them in an `\aftergroup`.  Hmm, interesting idea.

Comment: I tried this once by patching the pgfkeys source code inserting `\global` everywhere I could find an assignment.  Didn't work...so I hope you find a solution!

Comment: The `for` loop given by `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` from the `pgfplots` package might also be useful here. Its syntax is basically the same as the pgf `\foreach` loop, but the interior is at the same grouping level. Thus, assignments inside need not be global to affect what goes on outside.

Comment: Presumably now you'd use `remember` ....

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*Edit:* I just got my copy of *TeX by Topic* from Lulu, which of course means that my work day ended early :-). I stumpled upon `\globaldefs`, which allows one to answer the question actually asked with a yes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/tmp/.cd, foo/.initial = a, bar/.initial = z}
\def\showstatus{%
  (level: \the\currentgrouplevel\ -- 
   globaldefs: \the\globaldefs\ --
   foo: \pgfkeysvalueof{/tmp/foo} --
   bar: \pgfkeysvalueof{/tmp/bar})}

\showstatus

{\globaldefs=1\relax
  \foreach \k/\v in {{/tmp/foo}/bb,{/tmp/bar}/yy} { %
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{\k}{\v}
  }
  \showstatus
}

\showstatus

\end{document}
```

Here I implicitly use that `\globaldefs` is 0 (or non-positive), so that the assignment `\globaldefs=1` is local. If `\globaldefs` is already positive in the current scope, we don't need to set it; and in fact it would be wrong to do so (since *its* value might be local to some surrounding group; assigning it a positive value again would set it globally). Correcting this is left as an exercise.

*Original answer* Andrew, your comment about using `\aftergroup` led me to investigate. It turns out that the body of `\foreach` is actually performed *two* levels down. Assuming that what you really want is a way for `\foreach` to be able to set keys at the current scope (as opposed to actually setting them globally), this seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/tmp/.cd, foo/.initial = a, bar/.initial = z}

\def\showstatus{%
(\the\currentgrouplevel\ -- 
\pgfkeysvalueof{/tmp/foo} --
\pgfkeysvalueof{/tmp/bar})}

\makeatletter

\csdef{my@count}{0}
\newcommand*{\@csgincr}[1]{\csnumgdef{#1}{\csuse{#1} + 1}}

The initial status: \showstatus

\foreach \k/\v in {{/tmp/foo}/bb,{/tmp/bar}/yy} { %
  \@csgincr{my@count}%
%  \showstatus (\k, \v, \my@count)
  % Define a global macro which does the keyval-setting (locally), and
  % which then undefines itself
  \csxdef{@tmp@setkeyval@\my@count}{\noexpand\pgfkeyssetvalue{\k}{\v}%
    \noexpand\global\noexpand\csundef{@tmp@setkeyval@\my@count}}%
  % Define a global macro which when called, places the above
  % \aftergroup, and then undefines itself
  \csxdef{@tmp@export@\my@count}{\noexpand\aftergroup%
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname @tmp@setkeyval@\my@count\endcsname%
    \noexpand\global\noexpand\csundef{@tmp@export@\my@count}}%
  % Place the above \aftergroup
  \expandafter\aftergroup\csname @tmp@export@\my@count\endcsname%
%  \aftergroup\par
}

Now we have: \showstatus

{
Now we are on a level 1 group \showstatus
\foreach \k/\v in {{/tmp/foo}/ccc,{/tmp/bar}/xxx} { %
  \@csgincr{my@count}%
%  \showstatus (\k, \v, \my@count)
  \csxdef{@tmp@setkeyval@\my@count}{\noexpand\pgfkeyssetvalue{\k}{\v}%
    \noexpand\global\noexpand\csundef{@tmp@setkeyval@\my@count}}%
  \csxdef{@tmp@export@\my@count}{\noexpand\aftergroup%
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname @tmp@setkeyval@\my@count\endcsname%
    \noexpand\global\noexpand\csundef{@tmp@export@\my@count}}%
  %
  \expandafter\aftergroup\csname @tmp@export@\my@count\endcsname%
%  \aftergroup\par
}
The keys have been updated \showstatus
}

but only inside the group \showstatus

\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you should get a detective badge for this!

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks, and please see the updated answer.

Comment: That is fantastic.  I think that both your solutions are useful, so I'm glad you left the earlier one in there.  And with the added bonus that I now understand why one might want to mess with `\globaldefs`!  (And as if that weren't enough, I'm left with the image of Lulu sending you a book.  If you're confused, take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lulu_%28singer%29 )

Comment: It is probably safer to have the `\globaldefs` inside the loop, so that the the looping code is not affected. Or even better make a wrapper of `\pgfkeys` that locally sets `\globaldefs`.

Comment: @Caramdir: That's right. Would something as simple as `\def\pgfglobalkeys#1{\begingroup \ifnum\the\globaldefs>0\relax \else \globaldefs=1\fi \pgfkeys{#1}\endgroup}` work? (Provided of course that none of the key-setting business messes with `\globaldefs`.)

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, I thought that the original solution might have its uses, but it's not so much a "solution" as an example of a technique which can be implemented in a situation where one wants to set keys on level X (>0), but for some reason the stuff which does the key setting (or computes which keys to set to which values) happens on level Y > X. If Y = X+1 it would be much simpler; if Y > X+2 I won't try to do this :-) Btw, since the export mechanism heavily relies on being able to define helper macros on a global level, one might have to ensure that `\global` is not ignored. (tbc)

Comment: (continued) This basically amounts to wrapping each `\global` assignment in a group within which we make sure `\globaldefs` is not negative (while also making sure that `\globaldefs` retains its value immediately after the assignment).

Comment: `etextools` has a `\AfterGroup` that might be useful. It seems that you could condense a lot of that stuff down to `\AfterGroup\AfterGroup{*code*}`

Comment: A little late, but: I have always wondered how to do this.  Thanks!  A little note: if you use the handler `.list` to import the `\foreach` facilities into `pgfkeys`, then in fact the key definitions *are* global, as you can see from perusing the code.  So it looks like Till Tantau doesn't know how to do this either.

Answer (score 12):

I don't think `pgfkeys` allows for global assignments out-of-the-box.
However, you can define your own handler to define global values. The problem is that it wont work the same for all macros like `\pgfkeyssetvalue` keys like `.code`, `.store in`, `.style`, etc. You would have to look up their definitions and define global versions of these handlers, like `\pgfkeysgsetvalue` `.gcode`, `.gstore in`, `.gstyle`.

Here the implementations of `.gcode` and `\pgfkeysgsetvalue`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeysdef{/handlers/.gcode}{%
    \long\def\pgfkeys@temp ##1\pgfeov{#1}%
    \global\pgfkeyslet{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@cmd}{\pgfkeys@temp}%
}
\newcommand{\pgfkeysgsetvalue}[2]{%
    \pgfkeys@temptoks{#2}%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname pgfk@#1\endcsname{\the\pgfkeys@temptoks}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{test/.code={\message{NOOO}}}%
\pgfkeyssetvalue{test2}{\message{NOOO}}%
{%
\pgfkeys{test/.gcode={\message{WORKS}}}%
\pgfkeysgsetvalue{test2}{\message{WORKS AS WELL}}%
}
\pgfkeys{test}
\pgfkeysgetvalue{test2}{\test}\test

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is definitely the way to approach it.

Answer (score 6):

First, you want to use `\pgfkeyslet` instead of `\pgfkeyssetvalue`, since you want to use the key outside, where `\myvalue` is no longer defined, so you have to set the key to the contents of `\myvalue` instead of to `\myvalue` itself.
Second, the definition of `\pgfkeyslet` starts with `\expandafter\let`. As it happens, prefixing `\pgfkeyslet` with `\global` still affects the `\let` after the `expandafter`, so that

```
\foreach \mykey/\myvalue in {long/list, of/keys}
  {\global\pgfkeyslet{\mykey}{\myvalue}}
```

does what you want. This solution is a bit dirty since it depends on the internal definition of `\pgfkeyslet`.

Another solution is to forget about `\foreach` if it doesn't fit the bill and to use another [method for iterating about a comma separated list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159118/how-to-iterate-over-a-comma-separated-list). If you are free to choose the representation of the list that you want to iterate over, the simplest approach is the one proposed by Knuth in Appendix D of The TeXbook. Define the list as

```
\newcommand\mylist{\li{long}{list}\li{of}{keys}}
```

Now you can process the list items repeatedly by `\let`ing `\li` to a command that implements the loop body. In your example this would just be

```
\let\li\pgfkeyssetvalue
```

after which

```
\mylist
```

processes the key-value pairs. (Knuth proposed to use `\\` instead of `\li`, which might be dangerous in LaTeX.)

Answer (score 2):

For my purposes, it was most convenient to leave the pgfkeys code alone and save whatever changes had been made to the keys using the following macro:

```
\def\savekeycode#1{%
    \edef\temp{%
        \global\let\expandafter\noexpand\csname pgfk@#1/.@cmd\endcsname %
                   \expandafter\noexpand\csname pgfk@#1/.@cmd\endcsname %
        \global\let\expandafter\noexpand\csname pgfk@#1/.@body\endcsname %
                   \expandafter\noexpand\csname pgfk@#1/.@body\endcsname %
    }\temp%
}
```

This only works for keys that code for commands, which is fine with me, but you can make the following variant to also handle the case where the key contains a value:

```
\def\savekey#1{%
    \@ifundefined{pgfk@#1}{%
        \edef\temp{%
            \global\let\expandafter\noexpand\csname pgfk@#1/.@cmd\endcsname %
                       \expandafter\noexpand\csname pgfk@#1/.@cmd\endcsname %
            \global\let\expandafter\noexpand\csname pgfk@#1/.@body\endcsname %
                       \expandafter\noexpand\csname pgfk@#1/.@body\endcsname %
        }\temp %
    }{%
        \edef\temp{%
            \global\let\expandafter\noexpand\csname pgfk@#1\endcsname %
                       \expandafter\noexpand\csname pgfk@#1\endcsname %
        }\temp %
    }%
}
```

Then you can install this as a handler:

```
\pgfkeys{/handlers/.save key/.code={\savekey{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## In the spirit of pgfkeys: the .list handler

Assuming that what you really want is a looping mechanism to set keys at the current grouping level (as opposed to actually setting them globally), I guess the `.list` handler is what you are looking for.

Using it to handle a key such as`set key value pair/.style 2 args={#1={#2}}` does the trick. You could tune the argument pattern to your taste (in any case, the separator / of the foreach statement could be confused with a key path symbol for the first argument).

Although the manual entry for the `.list` handler says

> The list of values is processed using the foreach statement, so you can use the ... notation,

it seems this handler does not put each execution of its *commands* in a TEX group,
unlike the `foreach` statement.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/mykeyspath/.cd, foo/.initial = a, bar/.initial = x}
\def\showstatus{%
[group level=\the\currentgrouplevel , % 
foo=\pgfkeysvalueof{/mykeyspath/foo}, % 
bar=\pgfkeysvalueof{/mykeyspath/bar}]}
Initial status of two value storing keys: \showstatus .

The problem.
The status during the foreach loop shows that 
each execution is actually performed two grouping levels down, 
and the effect of the pgfkeys commands only lasts one iteration:%
\foreach \mykey/\myvalue in {foo/b,bar/y} { 
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/mykeyspath/\mykey}{\myvalue}\showstatus }.

Indeed, after completion of the foreach loop, 
the status is back to initial: \showstatus . 

\pgfkeys{set key value pair/.style 2 args={#1={#2}}}% preambule matter 
\pgfkeys{% 
  /mykeyspath/.cd,% sets the default path to the common part of listed keys
  /set key value pair/.list={{foo}{b},{bar}{y}}% calls a loop on this list
}
The remedy.
After using the .list handler on a suitable key, 
the status is modified as expected: \showstatus . 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!  This looks really useful.  Next time I need to do this, I'll try this version.