# Is there a \foreach function that works in the preamble?

Tags: tikz-pgf, preamble, foreach, arrays

Tikz/PGF has an extremely useful implementation of \foreach, which allows for instance the construction

```
\foreach \x / \y in {1/a,2/b,3/c,4/d} {\x is a lot like \y}
```

in which you can iterate over a pair of lists.  This command only works within a tikz environment, so in particular doesn't work in the preamble, where I want to use it for defining a huge number of very similar looking macros, with say `\newcommand{\task\x}{\function\y}`; (really I'm defining new shapes in tikz, each of which is fifty or more lines of code, so just repeating it all a few hundred times is genuinely impractical).

Is there a function in tex that will easily do something similar?  I am aware that I could hack together this functionality using ForArray functions or nested forloops, but the results seemed like they would be comparatively inelegant, and I hoped someone here might have a clean approach (or a clean implementation using arrays or loops).

Comment: `\foreach` doesn't have to be in a `tikzpicture`, it also works in the preamble. The problem is that you won't be able to define new commands inside the loop, as each iteration is executed inside a local group, so definitions won't be global. Note also that you have the syntax wrong, it should be `in {1/a,2/b,3/c,4/d}`. Maybe you could add some more detail about what kinds of shapes you're trying to define? I'm sure that if they can be defined in a for-loop, they can also be parametrised, which would probably be a better approach.

Comment: You could either use `\gdef` or say `\newcommand\foo{...}\global\let\foo\foo`, but in both cases you would need to expand `\x` and `\y` before the definition.

Comment: With regard to the grouping of `\foreach`, take a look at the answers to this question of mine: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15204/86

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `\xdef` (global expanding definition) together with `\csname ... \endcsname` inside `\foreach` in the preamble. It works in the preamble but encloses the content in a group which requires the global definition. The loop "variables" (macros) must be expanded before/during the definition, otherwise the macros will just contain `\y` and not its current content.

Here an example how to define macros like `\mymacroa`, `\mymacrob`, etc., which will contain a call to `\dostuff` which gets the `\y` content.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\foreach \x/\y in {a/1,b/2,c/3,d/4} {
    \expandafter\xdef\csname mymacro\x\endcsname{%
        \noexpand\dostuff{\y}%
    }%
}

\newcommand{\dostuff}[1]{\texttt{(#1)}}

\begin{document}

\mymacroa

\mymacrob

\mymacroc

\mymacrod

\end{document}
```

If you want to do something different like defining a PGF shape than it would be better if you simply accumulate the required macro calls with the loop variables expanded and execute the accumulator afterwards.

The following code adds `\dostuff{<x>}{<y>}` to `\mycommands` which is executed after the loop outside any group. It then contains `\dostuff {a}{1}\dostuff {b}{2}\dostuff {c}{3}\dostuff {d}{4}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\mycommands}{}

\newcommand{\dostuff}[2]{%
    \pgfdeclareshape{#1}{%
        \anchor{#2}{...}%
    }%
}

\foreach \x/\y in {a/1,b/2,c/3,d/4} {%
    \xappto{\mycommands}{\noexpand\dostuff{\x}{\y}}%
}
%\show\mycommands
\mycommands

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With `etoolbox`, I'd get rid of `pgffor`. It's somewhat hard to use the expansion tricks.

Comment: @Leo: If you use a helper macro like `\dostuff` which simply accepts the expanded macros there shouldn't be any issue with the expansion. If `\x` and `\y` are complex they are better written as `\expandonce\x` and `\expandonce\y`.

Comment: `\xdef`, `\noexpand`, `\expandonce`... I can do it, but often make mistakes. Expansion is always a blackhole in TeX. That's why I don't like it. I prefer `\docsvlist` or `\forcsvlist`, which take the loop variable a argument — then there's no expansion issue at all.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations.  I wish I'd known this functionality ages ago.

Answer (score 2):

`pgffor` does work outside `tikzpicture` environment, although it is not robust enought for some applications.

One problem is, you wrongly use `\newcommand`. You can't use `\newcommand{\task\x}{\function\y}`, use `\@namedef{task\x}{\function\y}` or something similar instead.

The other problem is due to `pgffor`. It is executed in a group, and you must expand the variable when define a new macro using it.

Example solution, you must control the expansion of `\x` and `\y` carefully:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\foreach \x/\y in {a/1,b/2,c/3} {
  \expandafter\xdef\csname cmd\x\endcsname{number \y}
}
\begin{document}
\cmda, \cmdb, \cmdc
\end{document}
```

Another solution using `etoolbox`, this is preferred:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\def\dodo#1/#2{\csdef{cmd#1}{number #2}}
\def\do#1{\dodo#1}
\docsvlist{a/1,b/2,c/3}
\begin{document}
\cmda, \cmdb, \cmdc
% we obtain: number 1, number 2, number 3
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the catoptions package the auxiliary `\dodo` is not necessary and you can also use an arbitrary list separator. Also, each element of the list is first trimmed of spurious leading and trailing spaces before `\do` takes effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}[2011/10/22]

\begin{document}

\def\do#1/#2{\csndef*{cmd#1}{number #2}}
\dofunclist{a/1, b/2, c/3}

%\dofunclist[;]{a/1; b/2; c/3}
\cmda, \cmdb, \cmdc

\end{document}
```