# Comparing reference numbers

Tags: macros, cross-referencing

I'm using the [`refcount` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/refcount) to get the reference number associated with a label. I'd like to determine whether two references lay "next" to each other or not, that is: I'd like an *expandable* command of the form:

```
\comparerefs{refOne}{refTwo}
```

that would yield `0` if `refOne` is equal to `refTwo`, `1` if `refOne` is *immediately before* `refTwo`, `2` if `refOne` is *immediately after* `refTwo`, and `3` in any other case.

Merely calling `\getrefnumber` (from the `refcount` package), saving the result into a counter and adding/subtracting 1 doesn't work for two resons:

1. If `refOne` refers to a section (and we're using the `book` class), `\getrefnumber` return `1.1` and setting the counter breaks.
2. Even if one were to get the section number only, one has to be careful because section 1 of chapter 1 is *not* immediately before section 2 of chapter 2.

This should obviously work with "deeper" references (ie. references to sub-subsections and the like).

To clarify: assume `refOne` is of the form `a.b.c` and `refTwo` of the form `d.e.f`, then `\comparerefs{refOne}{refTwo}` should return `0` if `a` = `d`, `b` = `e`, and `c` = `f`; `\comparerefs{refOne}{refTwo}` should return `1` if `a` = `d`, `b` = `e`, and `c` = `f - 1`; `\comparerefs{refOne}{refTwo}` should return `2` if `a` = `d`, `b` = `e`, and `c` = `f + 1`; and `\comparerefs{refOne}{refTwo}` should return `3` if `a` != `d`, or `b` != `e`, or `c` != `f - 1`, `f`, `f + 1` or if `refOne` and `refTwo` are of different lengths.

Ideas?

Comment: I spent a while on this, but then I checked and saw that you want an *expandable* solution.  Since it is hard even with the nice programming interface of `pgfkeys`, I'm giving up.  Are you *sure* it has to be expandable?  Doing something like `\comparerefs{refone}{reftwo}{\result}` and then working with the expandable macro `\result` may be enough unless this is nested deeply in some other expansion-only context.

Comment: @RyanReich: looking backwards I have to honestly say I don't recall exactly _why_ I wanted it to be expandable :P... I guess it's fine if it's not, better if it is... Care to share your non-expandable solution? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## First answer

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{xparse,refcount,etoolbox}
\newcounter{comparerefs}
\newcommand{\comparerefs}[2]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\docomparerefs{\getrefnumber{#1}}{\getrefnumber{#2}}}\x}
\NewDocumentCommand{\docomparerefs}{ >{\SplitArgument{2}{.}}m >{\SplitArgument{2}{.}}m }{
  \xcomparerefs#1#2}

\newcommand\xcomparerefs[6]{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifstrequal{#1}{0}} or test {\ifstrequal{#4}{0}} }% reference is undefined
    {\setcounter{comparerefs}{-1}}
    {\ycomparerefs{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}%
}
\newcommand{\ycomparerefs}[6]{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifstrequal{#3}{\NoValue}} and test {\ifstrequal{#6}{\NoValue}} }
    {\zcomparerefs{#1}{#2}{#4}{#5}}
    {\subseccomparerefs{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}%
}
\newcommand{\zcomparerefs}[4]{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifstrequal{#2}{\NoValue}} and test {\ifstrequal{#4}{\NoValue}} }
    {\chapcomparerefs{#1}{#3}}
    {\seccomparerefs{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
}
\newcommand{\chapcomparerefs}[2]{%
  \ifnum#1=#2\relax
    \setcounter{comparerefs}{0}%
  \else
    \ifnum#1=\numexpr#2-1\relax\relax
      \setcounter{comparerefs}{1}%
    \else
      \ifnum#1=\numexpr#2+1\relax\relax
        \setcounter{comparerefs}{2}%
      \else
        \setcounter{comparerefs}{3}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\seccomparerefs}[4]{%
  \ifnum#1=#3\relax
    \chapcomparerefs{#2}{#4}%
  \else
    \setcounter{comparerefs}{3}%
  \fi}
\newcommand{\subseccomparerefs}[6]{%
  \ifnum#1=#4\relax
    \seccomparerefs{#2}{#3}{#5}{#6}%
  \else
    \setcounter{comparerefs}{3}%
  \fi
}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Abc}\label{x}
\section{Abc}
\subsection{Def}\label{A}
\subsection{Ghi}\label{B}

\section{XXX}
\subsection{UUU}\label{C}

\chapter{YYY}\label{y}

\chapter{ZZZ}\label{z}

%\comparerefs{x}{x}\showthe\value{comparerefs}
%\comparerefs{x}{y}\showthe\value{comparerefs}
%\comparerefs{y}{x}\showthe\value{comparerefs}
%\comparerefs{x}{z}\showthe\value{comparerefs}

\comparerefs{A}{A}\showthe\value{comparerefs}
\comparerefs{A}{B}\showthe\value{comparerefs}
\comparerefs{B}{A}\showthe\value{comparerefs}
\comparerefs{A}{C}\showthe\value{comparerefs}


\end{document}
```

I use the `\SplitArgument` feature of **xparse** to get the references already split in components. I support only up to three levels (subsections) and there is no check whether the references are not compatible.

If one of the references is not already resolved, the counter will be set to -1.

First we decide whether the references are to chapters, sections or subsections. So `\chapcomparerefs` is the main one and sets the counter to the requested value. In case of `\seccomparerefs` we check if the first components are equal and then we pass control to `\chapcomparerefs` on the second components, otherwise we set the counter to 3. Similarly for `\subseccomparerefs` which sets the counter to 3 if the first components are different, otherwise calls `\seccomparerefs`.

In case you compare different kinds of references you get a "Missing number" error.

## Second answer

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{xparse,refcount,etoolbox}
\newcounter{comparerefs}
\newcommand{\comparerefs}[2]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\docomparerefs{\getrefnumber{#1}}{\getrefnumber{#2}}}\x}
\NewDocumentCommand{\docomparerefs}{ >{\SplitArgument{20}{.}}m >{\SplitArgument{20}{.}}m }{
  \setcounter{comparerefs}{0}\begingroup
  \def\NoValue{-1000}\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\xcomparerefs#1\relax#2\relax}\x}

\def\xcomparerefs#1#2#3\relax#4#5#6\relax{%
  \ycomparerefs{#1}{#2}{#4}{#5}{{#2}#3\relax{#5}#6\relax}}
\def\ycomparerefs#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifnumcomp{#1}{=}{#3}} and 
     not ( test {\ifnumcomp{#2}{=}{-1000}} and test {\ifnumcomp{#4}{=}{-1000}} ) }
    {\xcomparerefs#5}
    {\decide{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
}
\def\decide#1#2#3#4{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifnumcomp{#2}{=}{-1000}} and test {\ifnumcomp{#4}{=}{-1000}} }
     {\ifnumcomp{#1}{=}{#3}{}{\xdecide{#1}{#3}}}
     {\ifnumcomp{#1}{=}{#3}{\xdecide{#2}{#4}}{\setcounter{comparerefs}{3}}}%
}
\def\xdecide#1#2{%
  \ifnumcomp{#1}{=}{#2-1}
    {\setcounter{comparerefs}{1}}
    {\ifnumcomp{#1}{=}{#2+1}
       {\setcounter{comparerefs}{2}}
       {\setcounter{comparerefs}{3}}%
    }
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Abc}\label{x}
\section{Abc}
\subsection{Def}\label{A}
\subsection{Ghi}\label{B}

\section{XXX}
\subsection{UUU}\label{C}

\chapter{YYY}\label{y}

\chapter{ZZZ}\label{z}

\comparerefs{x}{x}\showthe\value{comparerefs}
\comparerefs{x}{y}\showthe\value{comparerefs}
\comparerefs{y}{x}\showthe\value{comparerefs}
\comparerefs{x}{z}\showthe\value{comparerefs}

\comparerefs{A}{A}\showthe\value{comparerefs}
\comparerefs{A}{B}\showthe\value{comparerefs}
\comparerefs{B}{A}\showthe\value{comparerefs}
\comparerefs{A}{C}\showthe\value{comparerefs}

\comparerefs{A}{x}\showthe\value{comparerefs}
\end{document}
```

These macros allow for a maximum of twenty levels (which should be more than sufficient). Again **xparse** is used to get two lists of arguments from the references. I assume that no reference value is -1000. The result of the test is stored in the counter `comparerefs`.

## Third answer

This is the expandable version of the second answer (the `\edef` will testify this assertion). As a byproduct, the length of the strings is unlimited, provided they are all of the stated form, that is, numbers separated by periods. None of the numbers should be -1000, the special value used for terminating the recursion.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{refcount,etoolbox}
\newcommand{\comparerefs}[2]{%
  \expandafter\comparerefsA\expandafter{\romannumeral-`a\getrefnumber{#2}}{#1}}
\def\comparerefsA#1#2{%
  \expandafter\comparerefsB\expandafter{\romannumeral-`a\getrefnumber{#2}}{#1}}
\def\comparerefsB#1#2{%
  \xcomparerefs#1.-1000\relax#2.-1000\relax}

\def\xcomparerefs#1.#2.#3\relax#4.#5.#6\relax{%
  \ycomparerefs{#1}{#2}{#4}{#5}{#2.#3.-1000.-1000\relax#5.#6.-1000.-1000\relax}}
\def\ycomparerefs#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifboolexpe{ test {\ifnumcomp{#1}{=}{#3}} and 
     not ( test {\ifnumcomp{#2}{=}{-1000}} and test {\ifnumcomp{#4}{=}{-1000}} ) }
    {\xcomparerefs#5}
    {\decide{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
}
\def\decide#1#2#3#4{%
  \ifboolexpe{ test {\ifnumcomp{#2}{=}{-1000}} and test {\ifnumcomp{#4}{=}{-1000}} }
     {\ifnumcomp{#1}{=}{#3}{0}{\xdecide{#1}{#3}}}
     {\ifnumcomp{#1}{=}{#3}{\xdecide{#2}{#4}}{3}}%
}
\def\xdecide#1#2{%
  \ifnumcomp{#1}{=}{#2-1}
    {1}
    {\ifnumcomp{#1}{=}{#2+1}
       {2}
       {3}%
    }
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Abc}\label{x}
\section{Abc}
\subsection{Def}\label{A}
\subsection{Ghi}\label{B}

\section{XXX}
\subsection{UUU}\label{C}

\chapter{YYY}\label{y}

\chapter{ZZZ}\label{z}

\comparerefs{x}{y}\par
\comparerefs{y}{x}\par
\comparerefs{x}{z}\par

\comparerefs{A}{A}\par
\comparerefs{A}{B}\par
\comparerefs{B}{A}\par
\comparerefs{A}{C}\par

\comparerefs{A}{x}\par
\end{document}
```

### Comments on the "expandable" solution

The `\comparerefs` macro reads its arguments and first of all tries to get the expansions of `\getrefnumber` from them. I use the `` \romannumeral-`a `` trick, but twice: the `\expandafter` will reach `\romannumeral`, so from `\comparerefs{X}{Y}` we get

```
\comparerefsA{<expansion of \getrefnumber{Y}}{X}
```

that will be expanded to

```
\expandafter\comparerefsB\expandafter
  {\romannumeral-`a\getrefnumber{X}}
  {<expansion of \getrefnumber{Y}}
```

that will become

```
\comparerefsB{<expansion of \getrefnumber{X}}{<expansion of \getrefnumber{Y}}
```

Say that `\getrefnumber{X}` expands to `1.1.1` and `\getrefnumber{Y}` expands to `1.2` (different length); in this case the successive expansion will be

```
\xcomparerefs 1.1.1.-1000.-1000\relax 1.2.-1000.-1000\relax
```

The macro `\xcomparerefs` just picks up the numbers to compare and we'll get

```
\ycomparerefs{1}{1}{1}{2}{1.1.-1000\relax 2.-1000\relax}
```

The fifth argument will be used in case the recursion is started, to be fed again to `\xcomparerefs` (we add a `-1000` at the end to never run out of numbers, as the two sequences can be of different length).

The recursion is started if `#1=#3` and both `#2` and `#4` are different from -1000: in this case we can't decide the lexicographic order, so we chop off the first component and restart.

The final stage will happen when the above condition is not satisfied. If both `#2` and `#4` are -1000, we output 0 if `#1` and `#2` are equal (the two original sequences are indeed equal). Otherwise we choose what number to output by comparing `#1` and `#3`.

If `#2` and `#4` are not both -1000 we again compare `#1` and `#3`: if they are different the two sequences are "far away from each other" and we output 3; otherwise we choose the output by comparing `#2` and `#4`.

The decision macro looks at the two numbers and outputs 1 if the first is one less than the second, 2 if the first is one more than the second and 3 in all other cases.

All is expandable thanks to the `\ifboolexpe` macro provided by **etoolbox**.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your solution is not flexible enough. I've looked at the xparse manual and found the `\SplitList` argument processor, I tried to get something out of applying `\SplitList{.}` to the result of `\getrefnumber`, but the latter seems to always return something of the form `{1.1}` and `\SplitList` takes that as a single element (note the braces)...

Comment: @mpr In what sense it's not flexible enough?

Comment: sorry if I've been unclear. I'd like `\comparerefs` to handle an "arbitrary" amount of nested sectioning environments (ie. an arbitrary amount of terms in "a.b.c.d...") and to be able of comparing them using something similar to "lexicographic ordering". I don't think your solution works under this conditions, and it doesn't check for the length of the references.

Comment: @mpr Please, state in your question what should be done for references having different length.

Comment: I though I had: look at the bottom, where it says _"To clarify:"_, when they're of different lengths, the command should return `3`.

Comment: I must say... I'm amazed! I have to get some sleep now, but will test/comment further tomorrow.

Comment: One detail: Trying to compile your second answer with pdflatex I get a fatal error on line 47 =S

Comment: @mpr You should compile from a terminal, as `\show` will interrupt the compilation.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my obligatory `pgfkeys` answer.  It does what you want, minus expandability: it takes reference strings of any length (possibly unequal) and returns 0, 1, 2, or 3 according to whether they are equal, adjacent in the last component, or otherwise.  I do assume that their numbers are above -1000: you don't have any very negatively numbered sections, right?

### How it works: high-level

- The code has two parts: first, I convert the strings (e.g. `1.2.3` and `4.5.6`) into a form that I like better.  I decided early on that I was going to use `\foreach` to do the looping, and it allows "parallel processing" of the form `\x/\y in {1/4, 2/5, 3/6}`, so I need to split the references along periods and then recombine them by matching corresponding parts, separated by slashes.
- This operation also gives me the opportunity to fix unequal-length references: I decided that given `1.2.3` and `1.1`, the pairs would be `1/1, 2/1, 3/-1000`.  This is why I assume that sections are reasonably large.
- The second part of the code is the comparison.  It works exactly as you'd think: given a foreach loop of the form `\x/\y = {1/1, etc.}`, I just check successively how `\x` and `\y` compare and set the result accordingly.  I also check whether I had previously decided that the references were *unequal*: in that case, the result is always 3, because that means they differed somewhere other than the end.  This is always triggered if one of them is shorter than the other.

Now you can try to follow the code.  If you get stuck, there's more explanation after:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgffor,etoolbox}

\newcommand\comparerefs[2]{%
 \pgfkeys{
  /split and combine,
  reset,
  do = {#1.\Stop.}{#2.\Stop.},
 }%
 \pgfkeys{
  /lexicographic,
  compare adjacent/.expanded = {\pgfkeysvalueof{/split and combine/list of pairs}},
 }%
}

% To protect against \edef
\def\Stop{\noexpand\Stop}

\pgfkeys{
 /split and combine/.is family, /split and combine,
 do/.code 2 args = {%
  \GetPeriod{\beforeone}{\afterone}#1%
  \GetPeriod{\beforetwo}{\aftertwo}#2%
  \ifdefempty{\beforeone}
   {%
    \ifdefempty{\beforetwo}
     {\pgfkeysalso{next/.style = {}}}
     {\pgfkeysalso{list of pairs/.append/.expanded = {,-1000/\beforetwo}}}%
   }
   {%
    \ifdefempty{\beforetwo}
     {\pgfkeysalso{list of pairs/.append/.expanded = {,\beforeone/-1000}}}
     {\pgfkeysalso{list of pairs/.append/.expanded = {,\beforeone/\beforetwo}}}%
   }%   
  \pgfkeysalso{next}%
 },
 reset/.style = {
  list of pairs/.initial = {0/0},
  next/.style = loop,
 },
 loop/.style = {do/.expanded = {\afterone}{\aftertwo},},
}

% Low-level stuff
\makeatletter
\def\GetPeriod#1#2#3.{%
 \ifx\Stop#3%
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo
 \else
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo
 \fi
 {\def#1{}\def#2{\Stop.}}
 {\def#1{#3}\GetToStop#2}%
}
\def\GetToStop#1#2\Stop.{%
 \def#1{#2\Stop.}%
}
\makeatother

\pgfkeys{
 /handlers/.list pairs/.code = {%
  \edef\thiskey{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}%
  \foreach \x/\y in {#1} {%
   \globaldefs=1%
   \pgfkeysalso{\thiskey/.expanded = {\x}{\y}}%
   \globaldefs=0%
  }%
 }
}

\pgfkeys{
 /lexicographic/.is family, /lexicographic,
 compare adjacent/.style = {
  result/.initial = 0,
  compare one/.list pairs = {#1},
  result
 },
 compare one/.code 2 args = {%
  \ifnumequal{\pgfkeysvalueof{/lexicographic/result}}{0}
   {%
    \ifnumequal{#1}{#2}
     {\pgfkeysalso{result = 0}}
     {%
      \ifnumequal{#1 + 1}{#2}
       {\pgfkeysalso{result = 1}}
       {%
        \ifnumequal{#1}{#2 + 1}
         {\pgfkeysalso{result = 2}}
         {\pgfkeysalso{result = 3}}
       }%
     }%
   }%
   {%
    \pgfkeysalso{result = 3}%
    \breakforeach
   }%
 },
}

\begin{document}
 \setlength\parindent{0pt}
 \comparerefs{1}{1}

 \comparerefs{1}{2}

 \comparerefs{2}{1}

 \comparerefs{3}{1}

 \comparerefs{1.2}{1.2}

 \comparerefs{1.2}{1.3}

 \comparerefs{1.3}{1.2}

 \comparerefs{1.3}{1.1}

 \comparerefs{1.2.3}{2.2.3}

 \comparerefs{1.2.3}{1.3.3}

 \comparerefs{1.2.3}{1.1}

\end{document}
```

### How it works: low-level

My style with `pgfkeys` is to put everything in appropriately-named families, so we have two: `/split and combine` for the first phase, and `/lexicographic` for the second (it is a kind of lexicographic ordering, I guess).

Here's how `/split and combine` works:

- It's recursive: there's only one key, `do`, which fetches the first component of each reference, joins them (inserting `-1` as necessary), and then calls itself if either reference still has more parts.
- The fetching is done by a non-`pgfkeys` macro, `\GetPeriod`, which has do do some pattern-matching with delimited `\def` arguments.  It works like you'd expect, except that if it happens to find that the reference is out of parts, it doesn't make the `after` part empty: it puts the termination flag back in and returns it.  This way, the recursion can continue blithely until *both* `before` parts are empty.
- This also has my favorite trick in the code: `\Stop` is recursive, but it is also protected from expansion!  This way, if `\Stop` appears in an `\edef`, it expands to `\noexpand\Stop`, which expands to `\Stop`, then stops.  This allows me to fully expand the `after` parts when recursing, and yet not worry about infinite loops *or* about reinserting the `\Stop` the next time around.  Notwithstanding that I've been pushing `pgfkeys` as a superior substitute for TeX programming, this is the sort of thing that makes TeX fun.

And here is how `/lexicographic` works:

- `compare adjacent` calls `compare one` repeatedly for every pair of individual reference numbers.  That's about it.
- I did have to go and add a handler `.list pairs`, since `pgfkeys` doesn't have an interface to the "slash" syntax by default, and this caused me much trouble because `\foreach` buries its body inside groups so that everything is local.  I need `result` to be set once and for all, though, so that has to be overridden; the solution, as I learned from the answer to [Is there a way to set a *global* key value using `pgfkeys`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15204/575), is to set `\globaldefs=1`.  I try not to overdo it; no doubt I am already clobbering the save stack like this.

I am somewhat dissatisfied with the overuse of conditionals.  I really, really wanted to use `pgfkeys`' key-testing logic (`.try`/`.retry`) to implement `if/then/else` statements, but it doesn't work nicely.  It is, of course, possible to define a very general "`if, then, else`" key that does this, but I got lazy and just made it code.  I'm still profiting from `pgfkeys`, though, because of its easy `.expanded` handler and nice syntax.  Just not as much as I'd like.

Comment: That's some amazing coding/explanation effort! :) I'll have to test (and read) it thoroughly. Regarding `-1` appearing in the reference string... I don't know how references to `\part`s work... but their "level" _is_ `-1` (can't really tell how this affects your code though). Regarding `0` appearing in the reference string... I think this indeed could happen, I've seen (and suffered) "Section 0.1" appear in a few manuscripts of mine... what are your thoughts on this matter?

Comment: @mpr: The "level" is -1 but I think their numbers should still be positive.  Having a 0 show up in your references means that you wrote a `\subsection` without enclosing it in a `\section`, which is wrong, but (like you say) does happen.  I don't know how `refcount` works, though, so let's just change it to -1000 like egreg does.

Comment: You're quite right, thank you for modifying your code :) It's a tough call, deciding between your answer and @egreg's: I like your explanation better, but I like egre's one including less packages... can't I accept both of them?