# How can I escape the scope of an environment?

Tags: environments, scoping

Is there any way to escape the scope of an environment, e.g. to get the `\pgfplotsset` command in the MWE below have an effect on the subsequent plot?

(I know that `\newcommand` doesn't have this problem but that isn't the question.)

Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newenvironment{foo}{}{\pgfplotsset{axis x line=bottom};} % how can I make this pgfplotsset count?

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{foo}
\end{foo}

\begin{axis}
\addplot[domain=-3e-3:3e-3,samples=201]{exp(-x^2 / (2e-3^2)) / (1e-3 * sqrt(2*pi))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why your `\pgfplotsset` is in the `end`-environment section?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Yes.  I'm writing a lualatex routine that takes the complete verbatim contents of the foo environment and produces a `\pgfplotsset` command.  Obviously, that wouldn't be a MWE, so sticking the `\pgfplotsset` in the end environment section is the closest thing.  In particular, I really don't want it as part of the environment itself.

Comment: I am not sure, but it could be, that the end section is `grouped`?

Comment: Yes, it is grouped

Comment: Is there a way of escaping that?

Comment: There is an `\aftergroup` command, but I am unsure, if it works in this context

Comment: No, don't try it, it's of no use here. Try rather `\global\pgfplotsset`, but I am unsure about this too

Comment: Thanks!  But no, that doesn't work either. :(

Comment: `\global\pgfplotsset` won't work. Definition from [pgfplotscore.code.tex](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/tex/pgfplotscore.code.tex): `\def\pgfplotsset#{\pgfqkeys{/pgfplots}}`. The answers to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15204/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-global-key-value-using-pgfkeys can probably be used to solve your problem.

Comment: @Jubobs: I feared that ...

Comment: @Jubobs: will look into that.  Clearly not easy.  Thanks!!

Comment: Same question as [macros - How to control conditional statements within new commands and environments - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234078/how-to-control-conditional-statements-within-new-commands-and-environments/234086#234086) ; however this case may have special case (can force pgfplots global?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is to use `\aftergroup`, as suggested by Christian in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195029/how-can-i-escape-the-scope-of-an-environment/195033#comment451107_195029).

Note that this approach only allows you to "escape" the scope of the `foo` environment, i.e. one level up; if the `foo` environment is *not* at the global scope, the `pgfplots` settings will not be applied globally.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newenvironment{foo}{}{}
\newcommand\fixedpgfplotsset{\pgfplotsset{axis x line=bottom}}
\let\oldendfoo\endfoo
\def\endfoo{\oldendfoo\aftergroup\fixedpgfplotsset}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%\bgroup %(as an experiment, uncomment this group)
\begin{foo}
\end{foo}
%\egroup    

\begin{axis}
\addplot[domain=-3e-3:3e-3,samples=201]{exp(-x^2 / (2e-3^2)) / (1e-3 * sqrt(2*pi))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks again @Jubobs. The problem I'm having is that the contents of `\pgfplotsset` are generated inside the foo environment, so it won't work as stated.  I'll accept in anyway since it gave me an adequate understanding of the issues involved.  Playing around with your example produced a different question; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195080/using-latex-commands-inside-pgfplotsset

Comment: Incorporating something like `\expandafter\pgfplotsset\expandafter{\contents}` did the trick; thanks all for your help!