# pgfplots - How can I change an option (e.g. xlabel) for all subsequent groupplots?

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

If `xlabel` or `ylabel` are defined in the groupplots options, the values are used for all subsequent plots. Same with other options.

Can one change the `xlabel` for all following groupplots from one point on, without having to repeat the option for each groupplot? This comes in especially handy when one wants to define the values for `ymin` and `ymax` for each row in a `groupplots`-environment.

### Picture

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
tikz,
pgfplots,
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
group size=2 by 2,
horizontal sep=0.2cm,
vertical sep=1.5cm,
ylabels at=edge left,
yticklabels at=edge left,
},
%
ymin=300,
ymax=1300,
%
xlabel={The label for the x-axis},
ylabel={Some y-values},
%
scale ticks above exponent={2},
]
\nextgroupplot
\addplot+ coordinates{(2200,1200) (3100,500)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot+ coordinates{(2300,1200) (4000,400)};
\nextgroupplot[xlabel={Now I define another xlabel2}]
\addplot+ coordinates{(2400,1200) (4500,400)};
\nextgroupplot[xlabel={And here I have to repeat it otherwise the label for the first plots gets put here}, xlabel style={text width=5cm}]
\addplot+ coordinates{(2500,1200) (4600,400)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `\pgfplotsset{xlabel={label}}` work?

Comment: @darthbith No, only works for one plot when placed directly in front of it, otherwise it breaks the document.

Comment: For `xlabel` you can use the `\globaldefs` trick from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15263/586, but that doesn't appear to work for axis limits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't mind augmenting one internal macro of the `groupplots` library a little bit, you can define a new `sticky options` style that you can use in the optional argument to `\nextgroupplot[...]` to set options that will stay active for the remainder of the `groupplots` environment (or until you call `sticky options` again).

Putting the following code chunk into your preamble will make the `sticky options` available.

```
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    sticky options/.store in=\pgfplots@group@stickyoptions,
    sticky options={}
}

\def\pgfplots@group@nextplot[#1]{%
    % Check if it legal to produce another plot
    \ifnum\pgfplots@group@current@plot=\pgfplots@group@totalplots\relax
      \pgfplotswarning{groupplots/too many plots}{\the\pgfplots@group@current@plot}{\pgfplots@group@totalplots}\pgfeov
    \else
      % 
      % If there has been other plots before then end the plot
      % 
      \ifnum0<\pgfplots@group@current@plot\relax
        % DEBUG: \message{DEBUG: Ending plot}
        \endpgfplots@environment@opt
      \fi

      % Use a group so we can discard all the options that aren't sticky
      \begingroup
      % Execute the keys
      \pgfqkeys{/pgfplots}{#1}
      % Smuggle the contents of the sticky options key out of the group
      \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfplots@group@stickyoptions
      % End the group
      \endgroup
      % Prepare for next plot, increment plot, row and column
      \pgfplots@group@increment@numbers
      % DEBUG: \message{DEBUG: Cur. Plot: \the\pgfplots@group@current@plot. Current Row: \the\pgfplots@group@current@row. Current Column: \the\pgfplots@group@current@column.}    
      % Creation of the new axis environment
      \pgfplots@group@environment@create{#1, \pgfplots@group@stickyoptions}
    \fi
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    sticky options/.store in=\pgfplots@group@stickyoptions,
    sticky options={}
}

\def\pgfplots@group@nextplot[#1]{%
    % Check if it legal to produce another plot
    \ifnum\pgfplots@group@current@plot=\pgfplots@group@totalplots\relax
      \pgfplotswarning{groupplots/too many plots}{\the\pgfplots@group@current@plot}{\pgfplots@group@totalplots}\pgfeov
    \else
      % 
      % If there has been other plots before then end the plot
      % 
      \ifnum0<\pgfplots@group@current@plot\relax
        % DEBUG: \message{DEBUG: Ending plot}
        \endpgfplots@environment@opt
      \fi

      % Use a group so we can discard all the options that aren't sticky
      \begingroup
      % Execute the keys
      \pgfqkeys{/pgfplots}{#1}
      % Smuggle the contents of the sticky options key out of the group
      \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfplots@group@stickyoptions
      % End the group
      \endgroup
      % Prepare for next plot, increment plot, row and column
      \pgfplots@group@increment@numbers
      % DEBUG: \message{DEBUG: Cur. Plot: \the\pgfplots@group@current@plot. Current Row: \the\pgfplots@group@current@row. Current Column: \the\pgfplots@group@current@column.}    
      % Creation of the new axis environment
      \pgfplots@group@environment@create{#1, \pgfplots@group@stickyoptions}
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
group size=2 by 2,
horizontal sep=0.2cm,
vertical sep=1.5cm,
ylabels at=edge left,
yticklabels at=edge left,
},
%
ymin=300,
ymax=1300,
%
xlabel={The label for the x-axis},
ylabel={Some y-values},
%
scale ticks above exponent={2},
]
\nextgroupplot
\addplot+ coordinates{(2200,1200) (3100,500)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot+ coordinates{(2300,1200) (4000,400)};
\nextgroupplot[sticky options={xlabel={Now I define another xlabel2}, ymin=0}]
\addplot+ coordinates{(2400,1200) (4500,400)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot+ coordinates{(2500,1200) (4600,400)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If taking the small detour of saving the x-label in a macro is OK, you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
tikz,
pgfplots,
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\newcommand\somexlabel{Label for $x$-axis}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
group size=2 by 2,
horizontal sep=0.2cm,
vertical sep=1.5cm,
ylabels at=edge left,
yticklabels at=edge left,
},
%
ymin=300,
ymax=1300,
%
xlabel={\somexlabel},
ylabel={Some y-values},
%
scale ticks above exponent={2},
width=6.5cm
]
\nextgroupplot
\addplot+ coordinates{(2200,1200) (3100,500)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot+ coordinates{(2300,1200) (4000,400)};
\nextgroupplot
\xdef\somexlabel{New fancy label}
\addplot+ coordinates{(2400,1200) (4500,400)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot+ coordinates{(2500,1200) (4600,400)};

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not what I meant. I edited the op to clarify what I was looking for. :)

Comment: @henry I don't see how my answer doesn't do what you want, although it doesn't do it the way you suggest in your MWE.

Comment: Hm... I don't get how I could get it to work for multiple groupplots (as in, multiple figures) in a document then? You mean one should define as many `xlabelDESCRIPTION` as needed then?

Comment: @henry Well, yes. That is a (potentially significant) drawback, I know. If it is useless for your case, I can just delete my answer.

Comment: I thought quite a bit about it and truly think it is useless because it is not an improvment, really. I suppose I am looking for a "switch"-like command/method to get there.

Comment: @henry Fair enough, I'll delete in a bit. I think I considered adding the answer earlier but was unsure of whether it was useful or not. By the way, on second thought you don't need more than one macro, just do `\renewcommand\somexlabel{...}` before the `tikzpicture`, and add the `\xdef` within the `groupplot`, if needed.

Comment: Fwiw, you brought up the topic of deletion, I think it could/should stay. :)