# An environment for conditional compilation using a switch

Tags: compiling, conditionals, etoolbox

I want to bar certain parts of my document from compiling based on a toggle switch. The reason is that my books contain a lot of PGF diagrams and graphs and the whole book takes a lot of time to compile. The number of chapters is also huge. When I am writing a particular chapter, I usually comment out chapters corresponding to other `\input` or `\include` files.

I thought of creating a new environment which has a toggle switch to do this automatically. Just one comment/uncomment will instantly switch back and forth between single chapter document and full document.

This is my MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\edef\leftbracechar{\string{}
\edef\rightbracechar{\string}}

\newcommand{\dontcompile}{true} % 'true' is meaningless, any word should do
\newenvironment{condcompile}{ 
    \ifdef{\dontcompile} \leftbracechar } { \rightbracechar }    

\begin{document}

\begin{condcompile}
    \chapter{first} % a chapter is usually a seperate file but here this should do
    Text of first
\end{condcompile}

\chapter{second}
Text of second

\chapter{third}
Text of third

\end{document}
```

If I comment out the line `\newcommand{\dontcompile}{true}` I expect the document to behave as if all chapters are to be compiled and it seems to work well.

If I uncomment the line `\newcommand{\dontcompile}{true}`, I expect to omit the first chapter from compiling. Which it does but also produces a garbage page. Basicaly I want the line `\newcommand{\dontcompile}{true}` to act like a toggle switch.

Is there a way to rectify it?

Comment: You want to look at the `comment` package

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247379/how-to-easily-write-conditional-pages/249823#249823

Comment: @Andrew Thanks! It serves the purpose beautifully.