# Conditional compilation with multicols nested in a \newenvironment

Tags: compiling, conditionals, multicol

I wish to include a question/solution bank at the end of the chapter. I want to be able to control its printing via a single comment/uncomment operation. The MWE is an article but my intention is to produce a collection of books with 30+ chapters each. All the books share a common preamble file.

The questions are to be printed as a two column `multicol`. I am using a conditional compilation as outlined in [ [How to easily write conditional pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247379/how-to-easily-write-conditional-pages/249823#249823) ] I dont claim to understand it, but it has worked for me so far. The only problem I face is when nesting it inside a `\newenvironment`.

In particular, there are two problems (indicated in the MWE with PROB-1 and PROB-2 tags) I face here -

1. Nesting `multicol` in a new environment `qbank` throws up  compilation error. But nesting `multicol` in a `\newenvironment[quescol]` and nesting `quescol` in `qbank` seems to work. Which puzzles me. In any case I can possibly live with it but would still like to know the real reason.
2. The conditional compilation scheme does not work as desired. The MWE compiles correctly but I cannot comment out `\SelectPartsForCompilation{queb}` as desired. I cannot put `\DeclareCompilationNameOfBlock[queb]` outside `\begin{qbank}` block as `qbank` is in literally 100s of chapters (each in a separate file).

Actually nesting this conditional compilation scheme in any `\newenvironment` does produce a mess. PS: In my real documents there are several more compile tags besides `queb`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,pgffor,environ,exsheets}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247379/how-to-easily-write-conditional-pages/249823#249823
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pgfkeysgsetvalue}[2]{
    \pgfkeys@temptoks{#2}\expandafter\xdef\csname pgfk@#1\endcsname{\the\pgfkeys@temptoks}
}
\makeatother

\pgfkeys{/DeclareCompilationNameOfLine/.is family,/DeclareCompilationNameOfLine,
    set/.unknown/.code={
        \pgfkeysgsetvalue{/DeclareCompilationNameOfLine/\pgfkeyscurrentname}{1}
    },
    set/unset/.unknown/.code={
        \pgfkeysgsetvalue{/DeclareCompilationNameOfLine/\pgfkeyscurrentname}{0}
    }
}

\newif\ifPrintComment
\newcommand\SelectPartsForCompilation[1]{%
    \foreach \key in {#1}{\pgfkeys{/DeclareCompilationNameOfLine,set/\key} }
}
\newcommand\MakeSelection[1]{
    \PrintCommentfalse
    \foreach \key in {#1,all} {
        \pgfkeysifdefined{/DeclareCompilationNameOfLine/\key}%
        {\pgfkeysgetvalue{/DeclareCompilationNameOfLine/\key}{\temp}
            \ifnum\temp=1\global\PrintCommenttrue\fi% print if key=1
        }{}
    }
}

\newcommand\DeclareCompilationNameOfLine[2][]{\MakeSelection{#1}\ifPrintComment#2\fi}
\NewEnviron{DeclareCompilationNameOfBlock}[1][]{\MakeSelection{#1}\ifPrintComment\BODY\fi }

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\newenvironment{quescol}{ % PORB-1 :: I am forced to use this clunky envirnoment
        \begin{multicols}{2}    
    } {
        \end{multicols}
        \hrule
}

\newenvironment{qbank}{
        \medskip
        \DeclareCompilationNameOfBlock[queb]
        \hrule
        \begin{center}
            \textbf{\textit{\LARGE Question Bank}}
        \end{center}
        \hrule
        \quescol % PROB-1 :: if I directly use \begin{multicols}{2}, i get compliation error
    } {
        \endquescol
        \endDeclareCompilationNameOfBlock
}

% PROB-2 :: If I comment out the follwing line, it throws up a compilation error
\SelectPartsForCompilation{queb} % comment this line for not including the question bank in PDF

\begin{document}
    \section{first} Text of first
    \section{second} Text of second
    \section{third} Text of third
    \begin{qbank}
        \begin{question}
            Transitive
        \end{question}
        \begin{question}
            Reflexive
        \end{question}
        \begin{question}
            Symmetric
        \end{question}
    \end{qbank}
\end{document}
```