# Saving a PGFKey to the aux file

Tags: auxiliary-files, pgfkeys

I want to save the value of a particular key (from `pgfkeys`) into the `aux` file for my LaTeX document.  If it matters, I'm using LuaLaTeX, but the same problem is exhibited by XeLaTeX, pdfLaTeX, and the original LaTeX (producing `dvi` -> `ps` -> `pdf`).

Here is a minimal (non-)working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys{/test key/.initial=0}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeysvalueof{/test key}
\makeatletter\protected@write\@auxout{}{\protect\pgfkeys{/test key=2}}\makeatother
\pgfkeysvalueof{/test key}
\end{document}
```

The resulting `aux` file shows that the write was successful:

```
\relax 
\pgfkeys {/test key=2}
```

However, no matter how many times I run (Lua|Xe|pdf|)LaTeX, the displayed values are "0" and "0"; I am trying to make them (after at least two runs) display "2" and "2".

How can I get my intended results?  I would really like to stick with `pgfkeys` if at all possible; am I just going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's look at [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co) and how it reads the `.aux` file. For that, we look at how `\document` is defined in the LaTeX kernel:

```
\def\document{%
  ...
  \begingroup\@floatplacement\@dblfloatplacement
    \makeatletter\let\@writefile\@gobbletwo
    \global \let \@multiplelabels \relax
    \@input{\jobname.aux}% Reading of the .aux file
  \endgroup
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\openout\@mainaux\jobname.aux
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{\relax}%
  \fi
  ...
```

Note how the `.aux` file is read within a `\begingroup`...`\endgroup` scope.

Second, since [keys set through `\pgfkeys` as local by default](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15204/5764), you have to find a means to make them global, or at least survive the current scope.

One possible way is to set the keys written to the `.aux` using the hook `\@begindocumenthook`:

```
\makeatletter
\protected@write\@auxout{}{%
  \protect\providecommand\protect\@begindocumenthook{}% Make sure \@begindocumenthook is defined
  \protect\g@addto@macro\protect\@begindocumenthook{\protect\pgfkeys{/test key=2}}
}
\makeatother
```

or perhaps `\AfterGroup` (from [`etextools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etextools)):

```
\makeatletter
\protected@write\@auxout{}{%
  \protect\AfterGroup{\protect\pgfkeys{/test key=2}}
}
\makeatother
```

The former approach is similar to issuing `\AtBeginDocument{\pgfkeys{..}}` that ensures the key setting is local to the `document` environment. The latter ensures the same.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is much cleaner than just making everything implicitly global.

Answer (score 2):

I found the related question [Is there a way to set a *global* key value using `pgfkeys`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15204/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-global-key-value-using-pgfkeys); the following works perfectly, both for the MWE and for my actual use case:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys{/test key/.initial=0}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeysvalueof{/test key}
\makeatletter\protected@write\@auxout{}{{\globaldefs=1\relax\protect\pgfkeys{/test key=2}}}\makeatother
\pgfkeysvalueof{/test key}
\end{document}
```

I'd still be very interested in more elegant solutions, however.

Answer (score 2):

You can exploit the fact that the `.aux` file is read in *before* the tokens saved with `\AtBeginDocument` are executed.

```
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys{/test key/.initial=0}

\makeatletter
% at first reading, set the keys at begin document
\newcommand{\pgfkeysinaux}[1]{%
  \AtBeginDocument{\pgfkeys{#1}}%
}
% at end document the command should do nothing
\AtEndDocument{\let\pgfkeysinaux\@gobble}
% a handier interface for writing to the aux file
\newcommand{\writepgfkeys}[1]{%
  \write\@auxout{\unexpanded{\pgfkeysinaux{#1}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pgfkeysvalueof{/test key}

\writepgfkeys{/test key=2}

\pgfkeysvalueof{/test key}
\end{document}
```

[image]